# how to GRANT EXECUTE on MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

I updated the timezone on an AWS MySql instance, and tech support told me I also had to runt his command for each MySql user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PyupROCEDURE `mysql`.`store_time_zone` TO 'some_user'@'localhost';
```

I tried running without selecting a database and got this error:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

So then I ran:

```
use db2;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PyupROCEDURE `mysql`.`store_time_zone` TO 'some_user'@'localhpst';
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON PyupROCEDURE `mysql`.`store_time_zone` TO 'some_user'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

I looked at the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) and I don't see what would be wrong - here I want to grant access to a procedure and that seems to correspond to the docs:

```
GRANT
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    TO user_specification [, user_specification] ...
    [REQUIRE {NONE | ssl_option [[AND] ssl_option] ...}]
    [WITH {GRANT OPTION | resource_option} ...]

object_type: {
    TABLE
  | FUNCTION
  | PROCEDURE
}
```

And also this is how we created the procedure:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.store_time_zone ()
IF NOT (POSITION('rdsadmin@' IN CURRENT_USER()) = 1) THEN
SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/New_York';
END IF |
DELIMITER ;
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to run this command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `mysql`.`store_time_zone` TO 'user'@'%';
```

Here is why:

- The [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) grant exists at the global level
- The [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) grant exists at the database level
- The [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) grant does not exist at the table level
- The [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) grant does not exist at the column level

Here is how you can prove it:

User grants for MySQL exist in four(4) MyISAM tables

- `mysql.user` (Global grants)
- `mysql.db` (Database level grants)
- `mysql.tables_priv` (Table level grants)
- `mysql.columns_priv` (Column level grants)

If you run this query

```
mysql> select concat(table_schema,'.',table_name)
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_schema='mysql'
    -> and column_name='execute_priv';
+-------------------------------------+
| concat(table_schema,'.',table_name) |
+-------------------------------------+
| mysql.db                            |
| mysql.user                          |
+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

Only `mysql.user` and `mysql.db` have columns in the `mysql` schema representing the [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) privilege.

Therefore, these commands would work

```
# Global level EXECUTE privilege
GRANT EXECUTE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
# Database level EXECUTE privilege
GRANT EXECUTE ON `mysql`.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

Comment: Forgetting to add db level execution privileges caught me out thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party but the answer I found is as follows:

```
grant execute on procedure <procedure name> to 'username'@'hostname';
```

For stored functions the command is

```
grant execute on function <function name> to 'username'@'hostname';
```

These worked for me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! I don't know if this answer adds any more than has already been given? Perhaps you could expand on your answer - an example and a "before" and "after" in terms of `SHOW GRANTS`? Anyway, keep coming back, contributing and learning! :-)

Comment: @Vérace I think because the statement for functions was added as a bonus.

Comment: In the previous examples the procedure and function keywords were missing. If you take them out then the permissions are not granted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see that you need the 'procedure' keyword, try something like:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `mysql`.`store_time_zone` TO 'user'@'%';
```