# Maria/MySQL Possible to allow user to GRANT drop though not use DROP?

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

I'm setting up an SQL user (setup process for new websites) which will need to `GRANT` the `DROP` command to another user (admin user (for authenticated admins), *not* the public-facing user) though is there a way to prevent the user from *using* the `DROP` command itself (through SQL)?

No, I can not use an existing administrator-permission SQL user as the setup process is public facing.

I've read that an SQL user can not `GRANT` permissions it does not have though this was listed on a third-party website and not [Maria's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/).

Answer (score 1):

True, you cannot use the [GRANT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) to give away grants you don't own as stated in the [MySQL Documentation under the GRANT privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option):

> The GRANT OPTION privilege enables you to ***give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess***.

The only alternative would be to create a user that have the power to the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mysql.db SET
    db = '...',
    user = '...',
    host = '...'
;
UPDATE mysql.db SET Drop_priv = 'Y' WHERE ... ;`
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
```

The `INSERT IGNORE` adds the initial entry into `mysql.db` in case it did not already exist. Then, the `UPDATE` sets the `drop_priv` column to 'Y'. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` must be done manually is needed since no [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) command is ever executed ([GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) always executes [FLUSH PRIVILEGES;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html) automatically)

Create a Stored Procedure that accepts a database, user and host and executes these commands.

For the sake of example, suppose the following

- Database is `mydb`
- User is `'john'@'10.20.30.40`

The commands to run would be

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mysql.db SET
    db = 'mydb',
    user = 'john',
    host = '10.20.30.40'
;
UPDATE mysql.db SET Drop_priv='Y' WHERE db='mydb' AND user='john' AND host='10.20.30.40';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Place these commands in a stored procedure

First, login as `root@localhost`, then run the following:

```
USE mydb
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GiveAwayDrop;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GiveAwayDrop (givenDB VARCHAR(64),usr VARCHAR(64),hst VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO mysql.db SET
        db   = givenDB,
        user = usr,
        host = hst
    ;
    UPDATE mysql.db SET Drop_priv='Y' WHERE db=givenDB AND user=usr AND host=hst;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You must give away the [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) grant to the user, so that user can run stored procedures:

```
GRANT EXECUTE on mydb.* TO 'john'@'10.20.30.40';
```

See my old post [how to GRANT EXECUTE on MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97719/how-to-grant-execute-on-mysql) for further clarification.

Then, user `'john'@'10.20.30.40'` can execute

```
CALL mydb.GiveAwayDrop('givendb','fred','10.20.%');
```

to give out the [DROP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop) privilege to `'fred'@'10.20.%'`. This should work if `givendb` database exists and `'fred'@'10.20.%'` already exists in `mysql.user`.

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: That looks great though can you please state what you're doing conceptually/English first (edit it in or comment please)? I can't learn/understand new code if I don't understand the concept it's associated with. My best guess is that you're trying to limit the `DROP` command to only be triggered if the host is a certain IP but who is the host? The server? The client? Obviously it's only part of the whole concept.